# replace try catch into Try in scala

Tags: scala

```
 private def getDeviceDataByDeviceId(validId: String): Future[List[MonitoringData]] = {
    try {
      temperatureProcessorReadDAO.getTemperatureByDeviceId(validId).flatMap {
        case Nil => throw TemperatureNotFoundException(TransportErrorCode.NotFound,
          Error.DeviceErrorMessageForDataNotFound + validId)
        case listOfMonitoringData => Future(listOfMonitoringData)
      }

    } catch {
      case exception: Throwable => throw new Exception(exception.getMessage)
    }
```

I have to change this particular code of scala and replace try catch into Try 
this is what I have done but it is not correct

```
private def getDeviceDataByTimeInterval(validStartTime: String, validEndTime: String): Future[List[MonitoringData]] = {
    Try(temperatureProcessorReadDAO.getTemperatureByTimeInterval(validStartTime, validEndTime)) match {
      case Success(List()) => throw TemperatureNotFoundException(TransportErrorCode.NotFound,
        Error.TimeIntervalErrorMessageForDataNotFound + validStartTime + validEndTime)
      case Success(listOfMonitoringData) => listOfMonitoringData
      case Failure(exception) => throw new Exception(exception.getMessage)
    }
  }
```

can you tell me what can be correct answer

Comment: "it is not correct" isn't helpful, especially when you haven't provided a minimal example that potential answerers can try out themselves. You'll get better results (and help more people than just yourself) if you provide complete examples and specifics about the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need any `try` or `Try` there at all: it looks like `.getTemperatureByDeviceId` returns a `Future`, so it should not be throwing anything inline, and just return a failed `Future` if exception happens.

If it does throw inline, your best option is to fix it (it is a really bad idea to `throw` in a function that is supposed to return `Future`), or, if you can't for some reason, just put it inside a `flatMap`:

```
 Future
   .successful(validId)
   .flatMap(temperatureProcessorReadDAO.getTemperatureByDeviceId)
   .map {
     case Nil => throw TemperatureNotFoundException(...)
     case result => result
   }
```

As a side note, never catch `Throwable`, use `case NotFatal(exception) => ...` instead. In any case, your `catch` clause seems pretty pointless: you catch everything, throw away any useful information, like type or stack trace from the original exception, and then just throw a generic `Exception` with only the original message. Don't do that.